# Sql query date range in reverse

Tags: sql, select

Anyone know if I can make a reverse Between?

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE '01-01-2014' BETWEEN 'field1' AND 'field2';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "reverse between" you mean "not between", you can do:

```
where '2014-01-01' not between field1 and field2
```

You should use YYYY-MM-DD for date constants (the ISO standard).  Or explicitly convert from a string to a date using a specific conversion function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
TO_DATE('01-01-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
        BETWEEN 
         TRUNC(field1) AND TRUNC(field2);
```

Above query assumes your field1 and field2 belong to the "`DATE`" datatype.

Incase, field1 and field2 are strings then, your select query should be

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
TO_DATE('01-01-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
        BETWEEN 
         TO_DATE(field1,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(field2,'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

**EDIT:**

In oracle, `&&` is not valid, use `AND` instead.
For date comparision as string, you are using "YYYY-MM-DD" which would be valid, however, it is better to use `TO_DATE` Function since I assume data_expiracio would be a "`DATE`" datatype.

```
    SELECT grups.nom as grup, categoria.nom as categoria, zona.nombre as zona, ofertes.* FROM (((ofertes LEFT JOIN grups ON ofertes.id_grupo = grups.id) LEFT JOIN categoria ON ofertes.idcategoria = categoria.id) LEFT JOIN zona ON ofertes.idzona = zona.id) WHERE 
estat=1 
AND
data_expiracio >= TO_DATE('2014-06-10' , 'YYYY-MM-DD')

AND TO_DATE(2014-06-04,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN 
TRUNC(dataoferta) AND TRUNC(datavenciment) ORDER BY datavenciment ASC
```

Comment: SELECT grups.nom as grup, categoria.nom as categoria, zona.nombre as zona, ofertes.* FROM (((ofertes LEFT JOIN grups ON ofertes.id_grupo = grups.id) LEFT JOIN categoria ON ofertes.idcategoria = categoria.id) LEFT JOIN zona ON ofertes.idzona = zona.id) WHERE estat=1 && data_expiracio >= '2014-06-10' && TO_DATE(2014-06-04,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TRUNC(dataoferta) AND TRUNC(datavenciment) ORDER BY datavenciment ASC

No returns nothing and I have records with that data, without adding the date piece of work.

Comment: Refer Edit in my Answer

Comment: thanks for your help necesitava just put "not" before the "between"